# How to specialize a template-class with doubles?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I write a template class dependent on a given type and variadic types, like so:

```
template<typename ConstType,typename...Inputs>
class ConstantTensor;
```

Then I write another class, which is generally defined in this way (assume `wrong_type` whatever type you want, but which is different from the following specialization ):

```
template<typename T>
class X{
public:
using type=wrong_type;
}
```

And I also have a specialization of this kind:

```
template<typename ConstType,typename...Inputs>
class X< ConstantTensor< ConstType ,Inputs...>>
{
public:
using type=right_type;
}
```

My problem is that, if I define the type `ConstantTensor<ConstType,double>` and then I want to use  `X<ConstantTensor<ConstType,double>>::type`, the general case is called and not the specialization. So I obtain `wrong_type` instead of `right_type`. I guess it has to deal with the `double` type...Could you explain me why and how can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here a snippet of code, I hope it works:

```
class Scalar
{};


template<typename ConstType,typename...Inputs>
class ConstantTensor
{
  public:    
  constexpr ConstantTensor(const Inputs&...inputs)
  {}
};

template<typename ConstType,typename...Inputs>
constexpr auto Constant(const Inputs&...inputs)
{return ConstantTensor<ConstType,Inputs...>(inputs...);}

template<typename T>
class X{
public:
using type=int;
};

template<typename ConstType,typename...Inputs>
class X<ConstantTensor<ConstType,Inputs...>>{
public:
using type=char;
};

int main()
{
constexpr auto delta=Constant<Scalar>(2.0);
using type= X<decltype(delta)>::type; // this is int not char
}
```

Comment: cannot reproduce; please, can you add a full, but minimal, example that reproduce the problem?

Comment: I hope now is actually  clearer and there are no mistakes in the code I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
constexpr auto delta=Constant<Scalar>(2.0);
```

is a `constexpr` variable; so it's also `const`.

So `decltype(delta)` isn't `ConstantTensor<Scalar>` but is a `ConstantTensor<Scalar> const`.

You can verify adding `const` in partial specialization declaration

```
template<typename ConstType,typename...Inputs>
class X<ConstantTensor<ConstType,Inputs...> const>{ // <-- added const
public:
using type=char;
};
```

Now you get that `type` is `char`.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> Is there a short/elegant way to deal with both cases, const and non const, without duplicating the code?

I don't know if it's elegant, but it seems to me short enough: you can use a sort of self-inheritance adding the following partial specialization.

```
template <typename T>
class X<T const> : public X<T>
 { };
```

So `X<ConstantTensor<Scalar> const>` inherit from `X<ConstantTensor<Scalar>>`.

Comment: Is there a short/elegant way to deal with both cases, const and non const, without duplicating the code?

Comment: @Garo - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: It is not the same class, but I is still very short, so I would say It is totally fine, thanks!